# Creating a friends list in php/pdo and with three tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Like header says, trying to make a friends list in php using mysql and pdo.
Got three tables, one users and one friends and one details

Users:
id
username

Friends:
userID
friendID
status

Details:
profileImg

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM FF_Users 
LEFT JOIN FF_User_Details ON FF_User_Details.user_id = FF_Users.id 
LEFT JOIN FF_UserRoles ON FF_UserRoles.user_id = FF_Users.id
LEFT JOIN FF_ZIP_nb_NO ON FF_ZIP_nb_NO.Postnummer = FF_User_Details.zip
LEFT JOIN FF_User_Settings ON FF_User_Settings.user_id = FF_Users.id
INNER JOIN FF_MyFriends ON ((FF_MyFriends.user_id = FF_Users.id AND FF_Users.id) OR (FF_Users.id = FF_Users.id AND FF_MyFriends.user_id))
GROUP BY FF_Users.id') as $row) {
if ($isFriends) {
    echo '                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right read-only">';
echo '                      <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> ' . USERS_ADD_FRIEND;
echo '                    </button>';
} else {
echo '                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-xs read-only disabled">';
echo '                      <i class="fa fa-user"> </i> ' . USERS_IS_FRIEND;
echo '                    </button>';
}
}
```

What are I'm doing wrong here ? Only blank white page over and over.

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: First, check your error log, there might be useful clues there. Next, since we don't have your full code, try to perform a `var_dump` of your `$db->query()` results: maybe the query itself is not the problem but the rest of the code is.

Comment: @SolarBear - Not that i understand anything from the     var_dump it says: object(PDO)#2 (0) { } and for the rest of the code you are missing, is just echo the data out since it`s much html this page won`t let me post all. But i will update it to be correct db->query so you`ll see exactly what I'm trying to do. Thought just my post was the easiest way to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

Your comment about `var_dump` displaying `object(PDO)#2 (0) { }` lets me believe your query is simply not returning any data.

I'm not totally sure this is your problem since I don't have access to your data, but this line looks suspicious to me:

```
INNER JOIN FF_MyFriends ON (
    (FF_MyFriends.user_id = FF_Users.id AND FF_Users.id)
    OR
    (FF_Users.id = FF_Users.id AND FF_MyFriends.user_id)
)
```

1. First, your conditions are strange-looking.

   1. In the first part, you're comparing `FF_MyFriends.user_id = FF_Users.id`, which seems OK, and then `AND FF_Users.id` which looks strange. If you want to make sure that `FF_Users.id` is not NULL, I would suggest you check it explicitly (`AND FF_Users.id IS NOT NULL`).
   2. In the second part, you're comparing `FF_Users.id = FF_Users.id`, which will return true by definition. :)
2. You're using `LEFT JOIN` on every other table but `INNER JOIN` on that one. What that *could* mean is that no matching friends are found and that the database simply returns nothing since no matches have been done.

I suggest you a) reconsider whether you need an `INNER JOIN` and b) clean up your join condition.

I'm guessing a bit here but it looks like you're trying to fetch all of a user's friends, in any direction (ie. check for user A whether A is a friend of B or B is a friend of A). If that's the case, try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
-- etc.
INNER JOIN FF_MyFriends ON
    FF_Users.id = FF_MyFriends.friendID 
    OR FF_Users.id = FF_MyFriends.userID
```

The `DISTINCT` is important because if A is a friend of B and B of A, you'll end up with the same row twice.

I hope it helps. If it's not quite what you need, add a comment about what you need, exactly.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out here.
Let me explain exactly what needed to this page, a user logged into a system, the want to list all the members on the site. In this users list, they see a something like a v-card with images, location, age, birthday etc also a friend request button if not friends or is friends if already are that to. All those left join gets data from separate tables, user details, zip codes, user settings, user info, and hopefully tried to get the friends list bot not friends some friends. Explained better ? (hopefully)

Comment: It outputs every user now on site, but if tries to print out user/friends data, the same data prints out on every member. I may think i have to reconsider the hole sql request yes...